# Mongodb 4.0 bulkWrite is extremely slow while updating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, bulkupdate

I have a collection with more than 1 million user, I'm trying to update 
users balance on some event.

while I'm trying to update e.g. 299 row it takes up to 15739.901ms

no high load on the sever, it's just mongo running. I'm storing the database on an SSD Samsung evo 860 but MongoDB installed on an HDD.

Here's my function:

```
async usersUpdate(usersToUpdate){
const updates = [];
   return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
       users.forEach(user=>{

            updates.push(
               { "updateOne": {
                    "filter": { "userID": user.userID, 'balance':user.userBalance },
                    "update": { "$set": { "user.$.userBalance": user.newBalance } , "$addToSet":{'orders.$.orderID':user.OrderID} }
                }

               });

       }


       console.log('total updates' , updates.length);
       if (updates.length > 0){
           const DbConnection = await getConnection();
           const usersTable = DbConnection.collection('usersCollection');
           transactionsTable.bulkWrite(updates, {"ordered": false, writeConcern : { w : 0 } }, function(err, result) {
               // do something with result
               if (err) return reject(err);
               return resolve(result)

           });
       }else{
           return resolve('Nothing to update');
       }
   });
}
```

both userID and userBalance are indexed, and I set `writeconcern` equals to false.

I don't know what's the wrong with code and why it's super slow.

What's the problem and how could I speed up the progress a bit?

Mongodb config file:

```
storage:
  dbPath: "/ssd/mongodb"
  journal:
    enabled: false
```

Explain result:

```
{ queryPlanner: 
   { plannerVersion: 1,
     namespace: 'usersDB.usersCollection',
     indexFilterSet: false,
     parsedQuery: 
      { '$and': 
         [ { userID: 
              { '$eq': 'Kfasg3ffasg' } },
           { 'user.userBalance': { '$eq': 10 } } ] },
     winningPlan: 
      { stage: 'FETCH',
        filter: { 'user.userBalance': { '$eq': 10 } },
        inputStage: 
         { stage: 'IXSCAN',
           keyPattern: { userID: 1 },
           indexName: 'userID_1',
           isMultiKey: false,
           multiKeyPaths: { userID: [] },
           isUnique: true,
           isSparse: false,
           isPartial: false,
           indexVersion: 2,
           direction: 'forward',
           indexBounds: 
            { userID: 
               [ '["Kfasg3ffasg", "Kfasg3ffasg"]' ] } } },
     rejectedPlans: [] },
  executionStats: 
   { executionSuccess: true,
     nReturned: 1,
     executionTimeMillis: 24,
     totalKeysExamined: 1,
     totalDocsExamined: 1,
     executionStages: 
      { stage: 'FETCH',
        filter: { 'user.userBalance': { '$eq': 10 } },
        nReturned: 1,
        executionTimeMillisEstimate: 0,
        works: 2,
        advanced: 1,
        needTime: 0,
        needYield: 0,
        saveState: 0,
        restoreState: 0,
        isEOF: 1,
        invalidates: 0,
        docsExamined: 1,
        alreadyHasObj: 0,
        inputStage: 
         { stage: 'IXSCAN',
           nReturned: 1,
           executionTimeMillisEstimate: 0,
           works: 2,
           advanced: 1,
           needTime: 0,
           needYield: 0,
           saveState: 0,
           restoreState: 0,
           isEOF: 1,
           invalidates: 0,
           keyPattern: { userID: 1 },
           indexName: 'userID_1',
           isMultiKey: false,
           multiKeyPaths: { userID: [] },
           isUnique: true,
           isSparse: false,
           isPartial: false,
           indexVersion: 2,
           direction: 'forward',
           indexBounds: 
            { userID: 
               [ '["Kfasg3ffasg", "Kfasg3ffasg"]' ] },
           keysExamined: 1,
           seeks: 1,
           dupsTested: 0,
           dupsDropped: 0,
           seenInvalidated: 0 } },
     allPlansExecution: [] },
  serverInfo: 
   {  }
```

Comment: Could you share what it looks like when you `explain` a single update?

Comment: as Mongodb docs, updateOne() is not compatible with db.collection.explain().
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/
can you tell me how to do so using bulkwrite

Comment: Sorry! Run explain on the `find` portion of the update (so with a find rather than with an `updateOne`). It's generally a good idea to first check what it's doing to find the document befor eanything else

Comment: I just made an edit with the result, I see it's well indexed but I don't know where the problem is, maybe of the orders array? `orders.$.orderID` it's an indexed array as well and I ran find on it and exact same result

Comment: Hmmm, that explain looks normal to me. Any chance there are updates in there without a userID or with the same userID twice?

Comment: nothing at all, I don't think there are any locks right here